# Неправильно работает директива

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть директива, суть которой скрывать элемент если юзер это ресторан. Так вот, это работает только тогда когда в дочернем блоке нету `ng-show`, т.к. это все работает с помощью `display` `none, block`

```
WhenUserDirective.$inject = ['AuthService'];
function WhenUserDirective(AuthService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (AuthService.isRest()) {
                element.hide();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как сделать что бы элемент не рендерился, если условие выполнено, сейчас он просто скрывается ?
Да и это не лучшее решение, т.к. продвинутый юзер может посмотреть код и поставить `display: block`, а писать везде `ng-if` как-то не хочется

Comment: что значит везде? достаточно же одного места в шаблоне

Comment: а если проект большой ? и нужно не только в одном месте скрывать функционал

Comment: а что именно _это_? :) Смотри, на самом деле твоя директива, это ручная реализация того же самого ng-if.

Comment: ну нет, ng-if не рендерит если условие не выполнено, а это скрывает, мне нужно что бы не рендерилось

Comment: Ну так ты же как раз и хочешь, чтобы не рендерило?

Comment: да, но мне лучше это сделать в директиве, нежели чем инжектить сервис в контроллер, это же не в одной части приложения

Comment: Надо было эту причину писать в вопросе, а не _а писать везде ng-if как-то не хочется_ :-)

Comment: у element есть метод remove - он удаляет элемент из разметки

Comment: окей, как вариант очень подходит, а если допустим я добавлю в директиву событие (например, `user:logout`) и мне нужно будет снова показать элемент ? как тут быть ?

Comment: очевидно надо будет его добавить :-)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53825/discussion-between-grundy-and-jashka).